# Best structure for connection pooling with Java EE

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, connection

I am trying to figure out the best structure for connection pools so that I can access the connection pool from any servlet and establish a connection to my database. I have been following some tutorials in setting up and configuring the datasource and connection pool and they all have them initialized and accessed in classes that extend HttpServlet. So it looks something like this:

```
public class DatabaseConnector extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private Connection connection;
    private Statement statement;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        try {
            // Get DataSource
            Context initContext  = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/test");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public DatabaseConnector() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            // Get Connection and Statement
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT";
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1) + resultSet.getString(2) + resultSet.getString(3));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                if (resultSet != null) {resultSet.close();}
                if (statement != null) {statement.close();}
                if (connection != null) {connection.close();}   
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

It looks like to me that this connection pool is only for this servlet which would only distribute connections when a get request is sent the this servlets URL. What if I want to have another servlet that needs to access the database. I was thinking of just removing the doGet and doPost methods in this servlet and leave the init so that the connection pool would be initialized at runtime, and then have a singleton reference to this servlet which could be used in other servlets. However, this doesn't seem like the right way to me. What is the best way to structure a connection pool that can be accessed from all servlets and listeners?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're getting a connection from a DataSource (which is an interface to the connection pool). The DataSource is obtained from JNDI. If you use the same code in any other class of your webapp, the DataSource will be the same: all the class will thus get connections from the same DataSource, registered in JNDI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completely wrong.

The correct way to access a connection is to use a [JNDI connection pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncji.html).

Servlets are HTTP listeners.  They shouldn't have anything to do with databases.

A properly layered Java EE solution will restrict data sources to the service tier.  It will check connections in and out, know about units of work and transactions, and interact with data access objects.

Servlets should deal with services, not data sources.

Comment: Most certainly will be, not might be. Why would you bother with an unpooled data source?

Comment: Doesn't belong in a servlet, IMO.

Comment: Ok, you are talking about proper architecture for this, not how OP's retrieving it in `init()`.

Comment: Ya I thought it was wrong. It didn't seem right to me. Thanks for clarifying this for me! So I will probably do as Kevin Bowersox said, and just a single class for getting the connection. This makes much more sense now! thanks!

Comment: @Weasel The point is not to use the Connection in the Servlet either.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis right. So I was thinking I would have a DAO class that would use and handle the connection from the connection pool, and then through this DAO is how I would get the needed information which could be called from the servlet

Comment: One great advantage of leaving this code out of the servlet is that the DAO can be a POJO that you can test without requiring a servlet engine.

Comment: @duffymo ya I completely agree. I always try to make things as modular as possible. I was just confused with connection pools at first.

Comment: I am wondering how connections stay connected after request to Apache server (or any web server) are fulfilled. Does jdbc connections are shared between http requests to server? @duffymo

Comment: Not shared; should not be.  Ever.  This question was answered 7 years ago.  If you have a question, ask a new one.

Answer (score 2):

The logic to create a connection could be placed within a simple class.

```
public class ConnectionManager{
       public static Connection getConnection(){
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            // Get DataSource
            Context initContext  = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/test");
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       if(connection == null){
           throw new RuntimeException("Cannot connect");
       }

       return connection;
       }
}
```